# Partitioning a list fairly

Tags: list, haskell, partitioning

I'm sure this is a reasonably common thing but I can't find anything on it (my internet-search-fu is not strong).

I have a function that can group a list into a list of lists of N elements each, with the final sublist being smaller than N if the length of the list is not evenly divisible by N. Some examples:

```
groupEvery 2 [1,2,3,4]              = [[1,2],[3,4]]
groupEvery 4 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10]]
```

What I want is to take a list and a positive integer *n* (in the above examples *n* could be said to be 2 and 3) and partition it into a new list of *n* lists. It should work on a list of any type, and produce sublists whose sizes differ as little as possible.

So I would like to have:

```
fairPartition 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10]]
```

Or any combination of sublists as long as there are two of length 3 and one of length 4.

A naive attempt using groupEvery:

```
fairPartition :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
fairPartition n xs = groupEvery ((length xs `div` n) + 1) xs

fairPartition 4 [1..10] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10]]
```

but as you can see (3,3,3,1) is not a fair distribution of lengths, and for lists of smaller lengths it doesn't even return the right number of sublists:

```
# Haskell, at GHCi
*Main> let size = 4 in map (\l -> length . fairPartition 4 $ [1..l]) [size..25]
[2,3,3,4,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
```

I would like a {pseudo,actual}-code function or explanation that is easily translatable to Haskell (the identity translation would be the best!).

Thanks.

Comment: What about `transpose . groupEvery n` ? Does order matter or list elements can be treated as sets?

Comment: No, order doesn't matter to me, so that actually does it I think. Thanks! Though I would like to see an order-matters solution for curiosity and generality's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `split` package's [`splitPlaces`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:splitPlaces) function for this.

```
import Data.List.Split

fairPartition n xs = case length xs `quotRem` n of
    (q, r) -> splitPlaces (replicate r (q+1) ++ replicate (n-r) q) xs
```

Comment: Nice. I was looking for this (splitPlaces). Can't believe I missed it.